# Dynamically added HTML form fields not sensed through php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, dynamic-programming

I'm buidling a web service through which employees can enter worked hours for a given week. The form presents 7 days, and is thus subdivided in 7 `<fieldset>` tags. I also need to allow the employees to add fields to each day (and thus fieldset) in order to enter information on performed activities.

The form is built by a php loop, running an array containing 7 days. for identification, each day has it's own value varying from 0 to 6. This also goes for the button with which the user can add fields dynamically: that how it knows to which field set the fields should be added.

Now, this is all going perfect. Except for the fact that when I push the submit button, only the dynamically added fields from the first day appear in the `$_POST` array on my processing webpage.

The code I use to add fields:

```
var index = 0;
var amount = 0;    

function addField(p) {
    //declare new textfield for company key
    var keyField = document.createElement("input");
    keyField.type = 'text';
    keyField.placeholder = 'Klant';
    keyField.style.width = '50%';
    keyField.style.height = '16px';
    keyField.style.marginBottom = '5px';

    //declare textfield for hours value
    var valueField = document.createElement("input");
    valueField.type = 'text';

    valueField.placeholder = 'Uren';
    valueField.style.width = '30%';
    valueField.style.height = '16px';

    if(index == p) {
        amount = amount + 1;
        keyField.name = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 1;
        keyField.alt = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 1;
        valueField.name = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 2;
        valueField.alt = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 2;
    } else {
        index = p;
        amount = 1;
        keyField.name = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 1;
        keyField.alt = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 1;
        valueField.name = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 2;
        valueField.alt = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 2;                    }

    document.getElementById('urenForm'+p).appendChild(keyField);
    document.getElementById('urenForm'+p).appendChild(valueField);

}
```

this should output field names like:

```
[activityDay0-1-1], [activityDay0-1-2], [activityDay0-2-1], [activityDay0-2-2].
```

The structure: `activityday<daynumber>-<activity in this day>-<keyfield = 1, valuefield = 2>`

Note that:

- Variable p is the number of the day, from 0 to 6
- each field set in the form is named urenForm. The fields are added to the correct field set in the form because the webpage dislays them perfectly.
- The already existing fields in the form from other days are sent. The problem only occurs on the dynamically added fields

Does anybody have an idea how I can make sure all the dynamically added fields can be sent?

Comment: Can you please provide the resulting HTML as well?

Comment: There are too many unknowns here. Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the UI and logs submit data to console. How do you know the data isn't received?

Comment: Where do you set `index`?

Comment: You're missing a `}` to match `else {`.

Comment: I forgot to copy the other }, that is not the problem in the code. I also edited the question with more information on how the form was built.

Answer (score 2):

Without too much info, I think the most possible cause is that the dynamically added fields have name collision.

Beside, you should consider [name your fields as arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays). So that you dont need to append an incremental number to each field name...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you copied this from a loop, so the variable `index` is not defined (or at a value resulting from the loop etc.).

You can try to replace this part of your code:

```
if(index == p) {
    amount = amount + 1;
    keyField.name = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 1;
    keyField.alt = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 1;
    valueField.name = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 2;
    valueField.alt = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 2;
} else {
    index = p;
    amount = 1;
    keyField.name = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 1;
    keyField.alt = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 1;
    valueField.name = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 2;
    valueField.alt = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 2;
}
```

by this one:

```
var amount = (document.getElementById('urenForm' + p).getElementsByTagName('input').length/2) + 1;
keyField.name = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 1;
keyField.alt = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 1;
valueField.name = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 2;
valueField.alt = 'activityDay' + p + "-" + amount + "-" + 2;
```

The first line simply counts the input fields and divides them by two (because always two input fields are added). This should result in the expected input field names.

I created a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/khPxz/)** to show how it works.

As Chris Lam already pointed out, it would be better (or at least clearer) to use arrays, e.g. like in [my answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24723967/2579421). This way you would not need the `amount` variable anymore.